# How do I delete a facebook post using $fb->delete?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can easily get and post, but now i need to delete, and i cannot using `$fb->post`. I do not know how to set it up the OOP way either.

```
$delete = $fb->delete('/' . $valuedel['id'] , $key['access_token']);
$delete = $delete->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah, i found the answer in some corner of the internet. For some extremely odd reason, you cannot do

```
$delete = $fb->delete('/' . $valuedel['id'] , $key['access_token']);
```

instead you have to have an empty array, lord knows why, so:

```
$delete = $fb->delete('/'. $valuedel['id'],array(),$key['access_token'] );
```